# Django 1.6 get filename of a file from database

Tags: django

I have a django 1.6.2 project with an app which is a store with products and a postgresql database. Everything is configured and goes well though getting images to show does not happen.

using

```
> <a href="/{{ p.mainphoto }}"><img HEIGHT=175 WIDTH=175 src="{{
> p.mainphoto.name }}"></a>
```

results in source showing this:

```
<a href="/webapps/static/images/14333.jpg"><img HEIGHT=175 WIDTH=175 src="/webapps/static/images/14333.jpg"></a>
```

which clearly doesn't work with displaying an image.

here is what my models looks like

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/static/images', blank=True)
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name)


class Product(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
    designers = models.ManyToManyField(Designer, blank=True, verbose_name = 'designer/artist')
    width = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits = 8, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    height = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits = 8, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    depth = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits = 8, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    diameter = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits = 8, decimal_places=1, null=True) 
    description = models.TextField()    
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color, blank=True)
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material, blank=True)
    mainphoto = models.ImageField(upload_to='/static/images', blank=True)
    morephotos = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage, blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)    
    price_in_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(FurnitureType, verbose_name = 'furniture/art type')
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.mainphoto.name)
```

here is what views looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.utils import timezone
from store.models import Product

def home(request):
        return render_to_response('homepage.html')

def designhomepage(request):
        return render_to_response('designserviceshome.html')

def eventspage(request):
        return render_to_response('events.html')

def aboutpage(request):
        return render_to_response('about.html')

def returnpage(request):
        return render_to_response('returnpolicy.html')

def privacypage(request):
        return render_to_response('privacypolicy.html')

def hello(request):
        name = ""
        html = "<html><body>Hi %s. </body></html>" % name
        return HttpResponse(html)

def hellonew(request):
        name = ""
        t = get_template('hello.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'name': name}))
        return HttpResponse(html)

def inventory(request):
        products = Product.objects.all()

        productinfo = {
        "product_detail": products
        }
        return render_to_response('inventory.html', productinfo, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from store.models import Product
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
# Examples:

    ... urls
    )

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

utlimately I will just want to get "14333.jpg" from the code below and add the website url before it and then let the python auto add the image name with the for loop let us know with your ideas of getting that thing in quotes

```
<a href="/webapps/static/images/1333.jpg"><img HEIGHT=175 WIDTH=175 src=""></a>
```

Comment: Ive found the following:

    `def save (self, **kwargs):
   import os
    super(Photo,self).save(**kwargs)

    new_name = '/'.join(self.file.file.name.split('/')    [0:-1] + ['%s.jpg' % self.id])
    os.rename(self.file.file.name, new_name)

    self.file = '/'.join(new_name.split('/')[-2:])

    super(Photo,self).save(**kwargs)

    photo_saved.send(sender=self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey('Product3', related_name='images')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/webapps/static', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.image.name)

def filename(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.image.name)


class Product3(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=300)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True) 
name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
designers = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
description = models.TextField()
quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
price_in_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
depth = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
diameter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/webapps/static', blank=True)
materials = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
style = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
timeperiods = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)  
additionalphotos = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImages, blank=True)



def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def filenamemain(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.photo.name)
```

Thats what the model looks like this important part is the def filename(self) part

Next was to add the correct call in the template as follows: (notice the {{p.filename}})

```
{%block body_content %}

    <div class="">

            <div id="manyphotos">
            {% for p in itemdetail %}
            <a href="http://www.yoursite.com/static/{{p.filename}}"><img HEIGHT=175 WIDTH=175 src="http://www.yoursite.com/static/{{p.filename}}" border="0"></a>
            {% endfor %}

            </div>


    </div>
```

{% endblock %}

this properly goes through the whole database with the proper primary key and displays all images available.

the view for this looks like this:

```
def itemdetailpage(request, id):
    property = Product3.objects.get(pk=id)
    property1 = property.images.all()
    itemin = {"itemdetail": property1 }
    return render_to_response('details.html', itemin, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```